# Delete all parse users with a certain value

Tags: ios, parse-platform

I am trying to delete all my Parse.com users that have a certain value. So if schoolName == NHS they should be deleted. I have code that might work but I am not confident in it and I would appreciate if someone could help confirm that this should work, and if this is the best way to do it.

```
Parse.Cloud.job("deleteUsers", function(request, status) 
Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();

var query = new Parse.Query("_User");
query.lessThan("schoolName", "NHS");
query.find({
    success: function(result) {
        for(var i=0; i<result.length; i++) {
            result[i].destroy({
                success: function(object) {
                    status.success("Delete job completed");
                    alert('Delete Successful');
                },
                error: function(object, error) {
                    status.error("Delete error :" + error);
                    alert('Delete failed');
                }
            });
        }
        status.success("Delete job completed");
    },
    error: function(error) {
        status.error("Error in delete query error: " + error);
        alert('Error in delete query');
    }
});
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you are afraid of making mistake, the following might help you and run your code. Using exportation to export all the data and you will receive it from your **Parse.com** email. Then, import all the exported data into the new app for testing. Then, it will not change your original app in **Parse.com**.

Comment: This is the best way to check if cloud code does what you expect it to do!

Answer (score 0):

using `for` to loop in your results won't work, try using promise instead:

```
Parse.Cloud.job("deleteUsers", function(request, status) {
    Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();
    var query = new Parse.Query("_User");
    query.lessThan("schoolName", "NHS");
    return query.find().then(function(users) {
        return Parse.Promise.when(results.map(function(user) {
            user.destroy();
        }));
    }).then(function() {
        status.success("Delete job completed");
    }, function(error) {
        status.error(error);
    });
});
```

to avoid delete data, just remove `user.destroy()` and replace it with `console.log(user.id)` to check with each objectId.